# Bootstrap slider set value issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slider

I use [bootstrap slider](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) and looking for a way to set a value of the handle from the input type="text"
I managed to set value for input from the handler, how do do it in opposite way?

```
$("#ex6").slider();
$("#ex6").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    $("#ex6SliderVal1").val(slideEvt.value[0]);
    $("#ex6SliderVal2").val(slideEvt.value[1]);
});
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb80vh2x/)

Please advise, thanks

Answer (score 12):

Use below's code to change handler value based on input text :

```js
var minSliderValue = $("#ex1").data("slider-min");
var maxSliderValue = $("#ex1").data("slider-max");

$('#ex1').slider({
    value : 0,
 formatter: function(value) {
  return 'Current value: ' + value;
 }
});

$("#inputValue").on("keyup", function() {
    var val = Math.abs(parseInt(this.value, 10) || minSliderValue);
    this.value = val > maxSliderValue ? maxSliderValue : val;
    $('#ex1').slider('setValue', val);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    padding : 20px;
    margin-top : 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/dependencies/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" />
    <hr />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" value="0" />
</div>
```

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/petalyaa/7bL7rjds/1/) for full implementation on changing value vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for your code, I tried to implement a slider with 2 handlers and 2 input fields. In documentation it is said, that SetValue can accept an array. I was trying to get values from two inputs into an array. but I doing something wrong

Comment: Remove `value : 0` from the slider option in javascript and it should work. Here you go [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/petalyaa/Lb80vh2x/2/)

Comment: @khairul.ikhwan I cannot get your fiddle to work both ways. The slider changes the input, but the input does not change the slider. Any ideas?

Comment: @khairul.ikhwan - Not sure what my problem was, but I tried it again. It worked! I appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you know how to do this without using jquery?