# Set the value of second Bootstrap slider based on change the value of first bootstrap slider dynamically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented two bootstrap slider in my project. and I want to change the value of second slider based on slide the first slider dynamically. but it is not working.

How I can achieve this?

My HTML code:-

```
<td><input id="ex1" type="text" value="" class="slider form-control" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="1500" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="1000" data-slider-orientation="vertical" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="show" data-slider-id="red"></td>

<td><input id="ex2" type="text" value="" class="slider form-control" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="2000" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="1200" data-slider-orientation="vertical" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="show" data-slider-id="blue"></td>
```

My Jquery Code as follow: but none of following method is working

```
$("#ex1").on("slide", function() {
    $("#ex2").attr('data-slider-value', '200'); 
});


$("#ex1").on("slide", function() {
    $("#ex2").val('200');   
});


$("#ex1").on("slide", function() {
    $("#ex2").attr('value', '200');
});
```

Comment: Does the event fire? E.g. test it with an alert for example.

Comment: Yes @frankenapps, Event is working

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658932/bootstrap-slider-set-value-issue

Comment: Thanks @Frankenapps its working fine. but using this code there are showing one extra slider in my page.

Comment: Well you should be able to remove it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have fixed my problem like this:

```
$("#ex1").on("slide", function() {  
var minSliderValue = $("#ex2").data("slider-min");
var maxSliderValue = $("#ex2").data("slider-max");

$('#ex2').slider({
 value : 0,
 reversed:true,
 formatter: function(value) {
 return 'Current value: ' + value;
 }
});

$("#aqua").hide();//hide duplicate slider based on id

var val = Math.abs(parseFloat(ownesAmt, 10) || minSliderValue);
this.value = val > maxSliderValue ? maxSliderValue : val;
$('#ex2').slider('setValue', val);
```

});